# when I am trying to run mapreduce application, it is not running or geting more time

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new for hadoop and try to setup hadoop multi node cluster with two data node in hadoop 2.6.0.But when I am trying to  run mapreduce application, it is not running  or geting more time.But all the demons are running well in each two nodes.

[hadoop@slave ~]$ jps
13406 MRAppMaster
9225 NodeManager
9072 DataNode
13591 Jps
[hadoop@master hadoop]$ jps
10051 Jps
3015 NodeManager
2444 SecondaryNameNode
1853 NameNode
2894 ResourceManager
2079 DataNode
[fail the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqI8T.jpg)

1.is this problem is coming because of memory problem
some time get more time to run the application 
[get more time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHC1U.jpg)

container_1455681046052_0008_01_000001-stderr
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: Can you add logs to your post..?

Comment: container_1455681046052_0008_01_000001-stderr log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: i dont know what do you mean  by logs plz can you tell me....@Krishna

Answer (score 0):

try bringing your jobhistory server up by "mapred historyserver" and submit the job again

Comment: please tell me what is the  jobhistory server how to up it

Comment: you can bring it up by issuing this command mapred historyserver.

Comment: it is used to track job history, I was getting an error where if it was not up, my job was not completing